# Analysis circuit using Thevenin theorem

Tags: thevenin, analysis

in the book "Engineering Circuit Analysis", example 5.9, i don't understand few things, hope someone can clear up for me:
[image]

Why does the dependent current can't flow through resistor 3k? If it's because of we assume 2 terminals of vx is open circuit then isn't we can't use KVL for the outer loop as it's not a loop?
And also i don't understand why vx = 8V = Voc

Comment: Current cannot flow via a 3k resistor because we have an open circuit on the right.

Comment: What you don't understand in the Vx = Voc = 8V.  Thevenin's equivalent Vth = Vx voltage is an open-circuit voltage (we disconnect the load when we want to find Thevenin's voltage).

Comment: Trust KVL and Isc to get Rth  and look here for intuitive validation with Falstad Sim https://tinyurl.com/ydetpfwe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just look at the voltages and currents that can only be when there is no load: -

[image]

Hence: -

$$V_x = 4 + V_x\left(\dfrac{2000}{4000}\right)\text{ or,}\hspace{1cm} V_x = 8$$

[image]